# The existence of an idempotent in some special semigroups

Tags: semigroups-and-monoids

> **Problem.** Does a semigroup $S$ have an idempotent, if there exist elements $b\in S$ and $a_1,\dots,a_n\in S$ such that $b\in \bigcup_{i=1}^na_ixSxa_i$ for every $x\in S$?

What is the answer to this problem for $n=1$?
More precisely,

> **Question.** Does a semigroup $S$ have an idempotent if there exist elements $a,b\in S$ such that $b\in axSxa$ for all $x\in S$?

Comment: Maybe something like the semigroup with generators a,b,c with relations bc=b=c, ab^ia=b, ac^ia=b with i\geq 1 works to give a counterexample. There is some overlap in these relation so maybe there is a big collapse.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg If $bc=b=c$, then $b=b^2$ is an idempotent, so this will not give us a desired counterexample...

Comment: That was a typo.  I meant bc=b=cb. Autocorrect removed the b.

Comment: Anyway I think what I suggested collapses.  Still it should not have to have an idempotent.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg In your example, $b^2$ is an idempotent. Indeed, by the associativity $bba=(aba)(aba)a=ab(a(aba)a)=abb$. Next, $b^4=b^3b=b^3(ab^2a)=b^3(b^2aa)=b(b^4aa)=bab^4a=bb=b^2$.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant that it collapsed.

Comment: I made the relations too simple

Comment: I meant your condition should not require an idempotent.

Comment: Note: the answer (to the last question) is yes for subsemigroups $S$ of groups. Indeed, for $x\in S$, write $b=axs_xxa$. Write $u=a^{-1}ba^{-1}$. Then $s_x$ is given as $s_x=x^{-1}ux^{-1}$; in particular $u=as_aa\in S$. Then $s_u=u^{-1}\in S$. Since $u,u^{-1}\in S$, we deduce $1\in S$. More generally in a cancelation semigroup, $s_x$ is determined by $x$ and one sees that $as_aas_{as_aa}$ is idempotent.

Comment: @YCor Yes, I know this fact, not only for cancellative, but also for semigreoups $X$ with finite-to-one shifts, which means that for every $a,b\in X$ the set $\{x\in X:ax=b\}\cup\{x\in X:xa=b\}$ is finite.

Comment: @TarasBanakh but I didn't know it and I spent a while, first trying example among those, then discarding those. It's useful if you provide such information in the question.